# Max coverage disjoint intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals, greedy, cover

Assume you have k<=10^5 intervals [a_i, b_i] \in [1,10^18] (some of them may overlap), and you need to choose a set of intervals mutually disjoint such that their union is maximal. Not maximum number of disjoint intervals, but the union must cover the most.

Can't try all possible subsets 2^k infeasible.
Greedy approaches ordering by a_i ( interval covering algorithm) and ordering by b_i ( maximum number of disjoint intervals algorithm ) didn't work
Can't figure out if there is a dynamic program solution.
Given the size of the input, I think the solution should be O(k log k) or O(k)

Examples
1. [1,4], [3,5], [5,9], [7, 18]
Sol [3,5]u[7,18]

2. [1,2], [2,6], [3,4], [5,7]
   Sol [1,2]u[3,4]u[5,7]
3. [2,30], [25,39], [30,40]
   Sol [2,30]

Comment: What are the number of intervals, the values of a_i, b_i at most?

Comment: Please also tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: you can sort them by the left border and compute `dp[i]`  = max union that ends with in `i`-th segment. It can be done in `O(k log k)` time if you keep track of events properly (or with a data structure like a segment tree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved in `O(k log(k))`.

First sort the intervals by their upper bounds (the `b_i`s). Let `I(1), I(2), ..., I(k)` be the list of sorted intervals. That is,

```
b_1 <= b_2 <= ... <= b_k
```

Denote by `w(i)` the length of interval `I(i)`. That is,

```
w(i) = b_i - a_i
```

Denote by `f(i)` the total length of the optimal solution among those whose last interval is `I(i)`. That is, the solution corresponding to `f(i)` is a set which:

1. contains the interval `I(i)`
2. doesn't contain any interval whose upper bound is above `b_i`
3. has the maximum cover among the sets of (non-overlapping) intervals satisfying 1+2

Now we are going to compute `f(1), f(2), ..., f(k)` and return the maximum value of them all. Clearly, the optimal solution corresponds to one of the `f(i)`s and therefore the maximal `f(i)` is the optimal solution.

To compute each `f(i)` we use dynamic programming. We do this by relying on the following recurrence relation:

```
f(i) = w(i) + max{f(j) | b_j < a_i}
```

I'll demonstrate the computation with your first input example:

```
I(1)=[1, 4],  w(1)=3
I(2)=[3, 5],  w(2)=2
I(3)=[5, 9],  w(3)=4
I(4)=[7, 18], w(4)=11
```

We compute `f(i)` for `i=1, 2, 3, 4`:

```
f(1) = w(1) + max{None} = 3 
    f(1) intervals: {I(1)}

f(2) = w(2) + max{None} = 2 
    f(2) intervals: {I(2)}

f(3) = w(3) + max{f(1)} = 4 + 1 = 5 
    f(3) intervals = {I(1), I(3)}

f(4) = w(4) + max{f(1), f(2)} = 11 + f(1) = 11 + 3 = 14 
    f(4) intervals = {I(1), I(4)}
```

The maximum `f(i)` is `f(4)` which corresponds to the set of intervals `{I(1), I(4)}`, the optimal solution.

Comment: thank you. I used a binary search to find max{f(j) | b_j < a_i}

Comment: Everything is ok, your explanation helped me a lot, I have already coded the problem and got Accepted
I can submit the code here, it may help other people in the future

Comment: i think, it is not O(k log(k)), finding max{f(j) | b_j < a_i} requires O(k) in worst case

Comment: @MukhtarBimurat: yes, but to know in which order you should compute the values f (in which order you consider the intervals), I don't see how to do it without having them sorted?

Comment: One calculation is wrong: `f(3) = w(3) + max{f(1)} = 4 + 1 = 5`  needs to be `4 + 3 = 7`

Comment: If you try to 3rd example this doesn't work. f(i) is not the maximum. You need to `max` one last time to get the optimal solution. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a **O(k * log(k))** solution. It can be achieved with segment tree data structure.

We may at first populate some **endPos** array of segment endings, sort it. Memorise for each of the segments corresponding **endPos** index. For this let **endPosIdx** be such array that **endPosIdx<sub>j</sub>** will store an index in **endPos** where the **j**-th segment ends.

Next we will introduce a segment tree. It will process the following requests:
1. `getMax(i)` - get maximum value on the range `[0, i]`.
2. `update(i, value)` - update maximum at `i`-th position with `value`.
**i** is and index in **endPos** array. Calling **getMax(i)** we ask for what maximum cover can we achieve if non of the segments ends after **endPos<sub>i</sub>**. Calling **update(i, value)** we say that now there exists a cover with length **value** ending at **endPos<sub>i</sub>**.

Sort all segments in increasing order by their starting position **a<sub>j</sub>**. Process them in that order. The gist is to find the largest cover if we will certainly take current segment in resulting set. Current cover will equal to the sum of the length of current segment and max cover of the segments ending **before** current. Let **j** be the index of current segment (they are sorted by start pos). Let **i** then be such max index that **endPos<sub>i</sub> ≤ a<sub>j</sub>** (**i** may be found from **j** by binary search). Then we can find

**cover<sub>j</sub> = length<sub>j</sub> + getMax(i)**

Next we should update segment tree calling **update(endPosIdx<sub>j</sub>, cover<sub>j</sub>)** and proceed to the next segment.

After processing of all the segments the solution can be found by calling **getMax(size(endPos))**.